# Conditional JSX in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to put together an element that may or may not have an  tag depending on the length of a prop:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class DarkLabel extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var icon, content;
        var rightIcon = '';
        ...

        if (this.props.content.length > 20) {
            content = <abbr title={this.props.content} />
            content.innerHTML = 'test';
            if(this.props.right_icon) {
                content += this.props.content.substr(0, 13) + '...';
            } else {
                content += this.props.content.substr(0, 18) + '...';
            }
                content += </abbr>;
        }
...
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, how can I get it to do what I want?

---

Here is how I solved it regardless:

```
if (this.props.content.length > 20) {
    content = (
        <abbr title={this.props.content}>
            {this.props.right_icon
                ? this.props.content.substr(0, 13) + "..."
                : this.props.content.substr(0, 18) + "..."}
        </abbr>
    );
} else {
    content = this.props.content;
}
```

Comment: That is slightly simpler than my question...

Comment: You can make content an array and push additional components to it.